# compiling cuda with gcc results in: error: ‘threadIdx’ undeclared

Tags: c, gcc, cuda, gpgpu, nvcc

How can I force GCC to compile with threadIdx lines in my code?

I'm attempting to compile my cuda application with a c wrapper.

To generate the .so file I run:
nvcc -arch=sm_11 -o libtest.so --shared -Xcompiler -fPIC main.cu

Then I attempt to compile the c wrapper with:
gcc -std=c99 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -o main -L. -ltest main.c

This results in the following error a few layers down in my code(an include to an included file):
error: ‘threadIdx’ undeclared

Note: Everything does compile and run just fine as a GPU application without any C wrapping.

Comment: threadIdx is a device built-in variable.  It should __only__ show up in device code.  Device code belongs in a .cu file and should be passed to the nvcc compiler only.  If you have threadIdx in your host code, something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Gcc has no capability to compile the cuda part of the code. You need nvcc to compile the code. gcc does not know what to do when it came across threadIdx is.